# Python conditional replacement based on element type

Tags: python

In Python 3.7 I am trying to remove pipe characters

```
r=(('ab|cd', 1, 'ab|cd', 1), ('ab|cd', 1, 'ab|cd', 1))
[[x.replace('|', '') for x in l] for l in r]
```

Error: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Desired outcome:
(('abcd', 1, 'abcd', 1), ('abcd', 1, 'abcd', 1))

How can I skip the replace command on elements that are not strings?

Comment: `… if isinstance(x, str) else …`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original `r` appears to be a tuple, not a list, so you may want to retain that as well. You can simply add the condition like this:

```
r=(('ab|cd', 1, 'ab|cd', 1), ('ab|cd', 1, 'ab|cd', 1))
[[x.replace('|', '') if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in l] for l in r]
```

And to retain the tuple type:

```
tuple(tuple(x.replace('|', '') if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in l) for l in r)
```